# GetExtra data not populating my cardview with item information

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im getting the data from my putextras, the thing is that it dosnt show the data accuarate, it seems like it show the data from the previous element in the list, or sometimes two previous elements from the list.

here is what im doing to save the data and put it into an extra

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = findViewById(R.id.list_view_database);
        userSearchView = findViewById(R.id.searchViewUsuario);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

       Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Usuarios");

        FirebaseListOptions<Usuarios> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Usuarios>()
                .setQuery(query, Usuarios.class)
                .setLayout(R.layout.item_row)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Usuarios>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, final Usuarios model, int position) {
                // Bind the Chat to the view
                // ...
                final TextView textName =  v.findViewById(R.id.NombreUsuario);
                textName.setText( model.getNombre());
                final TextView textEmail =  v.findViewById(R.id.Email);
                textEmail.setText("Email: " + model.getEmail());
                final TextView textPago =  v.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnPago);
                textPago.setText(model.getPago());

                //((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model.getEmail());
                mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                        mDatabase = adapter.getRef(position);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+mDatabase.getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserEdit.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Nombre",model.getNombre());
                        intent.putExtra("Email",model.getEmail());
                        intent.putExtra("Pago",model.getPago());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });


            }
        };
```

And here is where im getting the data

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cardview_usuario);
        mNombre = findViewById(R.id.NombreUsuario);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mToogleBtn = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

        Intent iin= getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

        if(b!=null)
        {
            String n =(String) b.get("Nombre");
            String e =(String) b.get("Email");
           final String p =(String) b.get("Pago");

            Log.e("Datos",""+n+e);

            mNombre.setText("Nombre: "+n);
            mEmail.setText("Email: "+e);
           // mNombre.setText("Nombre"+n);

            mToogleBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

                    if(p.equals("1")){
                        compoundButton.isChecked();
                    }
                   else{



                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

so, im getting wrong data from the extras.

Comment: A cleaner way would be to have a serializable Usuarios that you can put in your Intent. If the wrong values are received it means you put the wrong values in your Intent. You need to debug that part and to be sure to put the correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it passing the adapter with the item position, i was passing my model data but without the position where i was requesting it

```
 intent.putExtra("Nombre",adapter.getItem(position).getNombre());
                        intent.putExtra("Email",adapter.getItem(position).getEmail());
                        intent.putExtra("Pago",adapter.getItem(position).getPago());
```